# R - ggplot2 - plot regions as lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with regions and values.  Here's a toy example.

```
Start    End    Value
1        100     2
100      200     3
300      400     2
400      500     1
```

What I'd like to do is create a plot where each region (in line 1, that is `Start=1`, `End=100`) is plotted on the x, and the `Value` is on the y.  And preferably, I'd like to use ggplot2.  I have many different applications for this, but they all boil down to this one question.

What I'd end up with is a plot with flat (slope=0) lines for each region.  Here's an example of the type of plot **if you ignore the points, and just focus on the lines**.

[Copy number plot](http://massgenomics.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Exome-Focal-Amplification-chr17.jpg)

In words, you would have one plot, with (for the toy data) a line from x=1-100 with a y value of 2, then lines (x,y): (100-200, 3)(300-400, 2)(400-500, 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_segment` to draw line segments. See `?geom_segment` for details.

```
ggplot(df) + 
    geom_segment(aes(x = Start, xend = End, y = Value, yend = Value))
```

[image]

Using this data:

```
df = structure(list(Start = c(1L, 100L, 300L, 400L), End = c(100L, 
200L, 400L, 500L), Value = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Start", 
"End", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

You should probably check out some introductory `ggplot2` resources. There are lots of  suggestions in the [ggplot2 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ggplot2/info).

Comment: Thank you for the resource!